# How can set php array value in only one array

Tags: php, arrays, string, foreach

I have an array an add it in foreach loop my code is:

```
foreach($array as $a) {         
    echo var_dump($a);        
}
```

and my output is:

[image]

how can set my output to this:

[image]

and then show count of each value in my array. how can set this?

Comment: What's wrong with just `var_dump($array);` ?

Comment: This comment by Rikesh is the actual answer. Wait till it gets posted as an answer with up votes 10x

Answer (score 1):

Stony answer is good. But I realize you want to echo the length of the value that you have. So I just expanded Stony's answer.

```
$myarray = array();

foreach($array as $a) {         
    $myarray[] = $a;
}

foreach($myarray as $key => $value) {         
    echo "Length of $value at index $key is " . strlen($value) . " <br/> ";
}
```

Note that I use PHP function strlen to calcualate the length of the string. Hope this helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using FOR loop u can do this like

```
for($i=0;$i<=sizeof($array);$i++)
{
 echo $i."=>".$array[$i]."(length=".sizeof($array[$i]).")";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
    $arr = array("value1", "value2", "value3", "value4");
    $newArr = array();
    foreach ($arr as $val) {
        $newArr [] = "string '$val' (length=".strlen($val).")";
    }
    print_r($newArr);exit;
```

Expected output:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => string 'value1' (length=6)
    [1] => string 'value2' (length=6)
    [2] => string 'value3' (length=6)
    [3] => string 'value4' (length=6)
)
```

[Try Demo](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/8dt-rmx)